# Search documents that contain some text, but keep information about what field matches

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search

I'm learning node.js and mongodb. I'm learning by solving some problems. I want to make site that can search video database. Each video has title, description, author and a subarray of notes (you can think of it as a comments). Each note has a subarray of manual references to tags documents that exists in tags collection.
I need to search for some text in videos collection. For each resulting video I need to know if search criteria matches some of basic fields (author, title, description) or if some of its notes, including names of tags, matches criteria. Or both.

I know that this may not be right task for beginner but I would really like to make this work. I have some ideas about how to do this, but they probably are not good since I don't know much about mongo and it's capabilities.

What do you suggest, what should I use? Should I use text search capabilities + some aggregation? Should I offload some of work to be processed by application rather than mongo?

I probably don't need details, just directions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody answers, I decided to share my idea and how I did it. There is probably better solution, that is way I asked this question.

I did two separate queries using regex, that I merged results in application code.
I used ES6 Map to make union of these two sets.